# "Exception : Duplicate provide" when building Closure project with calcdeps.py

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm new to the [Closure Tools](https://developers.google.com/closure/). In this case I have a project structure like this:

[image: Closure project directory screenshot]

Using `calcdeps.py` to combine and compile my project, I got this exception:

> Exception: Duplicate provide (ClosureSample) in (D:\Tes compress\CSS\Stack\sample2.js, sample2.js)

I use the following command to invoke `calcdeps.py`:

> python calcdeps.py -i sample.js -p "D:\Tes compress" -p sample2.js -o compiled -c compiler.jar -f --js=sample_renaming_map.js -f --compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS -f --warning_level=VERBOSE -f --externs=jquery-1.7.js -f --js_output_file=sample_compiled.js

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the namespace `ClosureSample` is only provided by one call to [`goog.provide()`](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/base.js#83) across all of the JavaScript source files: sample.js, sample2.js, etc. If more than one file includes the line `goog.provide('ClosureSample')`, you will receive the duplicate provide exception.

Closure's `base.js` includes the following comment within the definition of `goog.provide()`:

```
// Ensure that the same namespace isn't provided twice. This is intended
// to teach new developers that 'goog.provide' is effectively a variable
// declaration. And when JSCompiler transforms goog.provide into a real
// variable declaration, the compiled JS should work the same as the raw
// JS--even when the raw JS uses goog.provide incorrectly.
```

In the command line invocation you may remove `-p sample2.js` since this file is already included by the path `-p "D:\Tes compress`.

> **Note:** The [`calcdeps.py`](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/calcdeps) script is deprecated. See Using [ClosureBuilder](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder) for information on `closurebuilder.py,` the new recommended dependency resolution script.